# Rename sections with ngerman

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, sections-paragraphs, naming

I am searching for a possibility to rename sections. I am using the ngerman package.

I have tried something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125231/how-to-rename-sections-in-latex, with `\subsectionname`, but it doesn't work.

With Google I can only find the constellation ngerman and babel.

Thanks for any advices.

EDIT:
So I am using babel again.

Here is the mini example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% Ändert den Style von paragraph ähnlich zu den von einen Unterkapitel
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
    \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
    {1ex \@plus .1ex}%
    {\raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\size@paragraph}%
}
% Ändert den Style von subparagraph ähnlich zu den von einen Unterkapitel
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{%
    \@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
    {1ex \@plus .1ex}%
    {\raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\size@subparagraph}%
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\autoref{sec:label1}
\autoref{sec:label2}
\autoref{sec:label3}
\autoref{sec:label4}

\subsection{Subtitle}
\label{sec:label1}
\subsubsection{Another subtitle}
\label{sec:label2}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\label{sec:label3}
\subparagraph{Subparagraph}
\label{sec:label4}
\end{document}
```

Label3 isn't really nice, because of the multiple **unter**. My idea is to replace them all with my own definition.

Comment: Since »[ngerman](http://ctan.org/pkg/ngerman)« is obsolete, »[babel](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel)« along with the language option `ngerman` is the way to go. For redefining names refer to the package manual. And finally it can't do any harm to add a proper [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to your question. Just for the case that you expect answers.

Comment: You can't find anything to renaming section names in the babel package manual. I don't really understand why in this case a minimal example is neccessary, but there it is.

Comment: The minimal example is necessary to see what you are exactly doing. And now that you provided one, we are able to help.

Comment: Page 15 of the `hyperref` manual provides the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not related to »[ngerman](http://ctan.org/pkg/ngerman)« or »[babel](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel)«, but more to »[hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)«. It defines the concerned names for its `\autoref` command. Section 4 (p. 15) of the package manual shows you how get those names redefined.

Comment: Could you add some code to make this answer self-contained?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example from the [documentation](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#TBL-25).

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\addto\extrasngerman{%  
  \def\subsectionautorefname{Unterkapitel}%  
}
```

And here the table of the relevant macros:

```
Macro               Default
-------------------------------
\figurename         Figure
\tablename          Table
\partname           Part
\appendixname       Appendix
\equationname       Equation
\Itemname           item
\chaptername        chapter
\sectionname        section
\subsectionname     subsection
\subsubsectionname  subsubsection
\paragraphname      paragraph
\Hfootnotename      footnote
\AMSname            Equation
\theoremname        Theorem
\page               page
```